# Django iterate on static files in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I'm struggling with this : in my template, I want to iterate on an array defined in my view, add '.png' to the end of each value so I can use them as `src` value for an `<img>` tag that I create while iterating. Here's my code :

```
<table>
    <tr>
      {% for iter in array %}
          {% with 'path/to/images/'|add:iter|add:'.png' as myImg %}
              <td><img src="{% static myImg %}" alt=""></td>
          {% endwith %}
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </table>
```

When I print `myImg`, its value is only '.png', without the `iter` value.

Maybe I can't use `with` tag inside a loop ? If so, how can I can concatenate my path, filename and extension ?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things.

All the `static` tag does is concatenate the value of `settings.STATIC_URL` with the filename. You can more easily do that yourself:

```
  {% get_static_prefix as STATIC_URL %}

  {% for iter in array %}
        <td><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ iter }}.png" alt=""></td>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Indeed this is much more simple, I don't know much about how work tags yet, I need to read more docs. Thank's a lot !